# pandas join using multiple columns

Tags: pandas

Got dataframes as below and am trying to join them based on "File_date" and "Symbol" which are common to both.

```
     df_clean.head(100)
              File_date Symbol hv20 hv50  hv100      Date  curiv    Days  Percentile  Close  Changed
        4609   20180423   ZYNE   68   64   64.0  180423.0  65.86   430.0        11.0  10.36        1

>>> df_clean.index
Int64Index([4609, 4611, 4608, 4606, 4603, 4600, 4609, 4607, 4604, 4604,
            ...
               0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 4617], dtype='int64', length=419721)





>>> df_allhv_to_date.head(100)
            hv5   hv10   dj20 Symbol
20180423  24.18  22.50  30.01      ZYNE

df_allhv_to_date.index
Int64Index([20171219, 20171220, 20171221, 20171222, 20171226, 20171227, 20171228, 20171229, 20180102, 20180103,
            ...
            20180410, 20180411, 20180412, 20180413, 20180416, 20180417, 20180418, 20180419, 20180420, 20180423], dtype='int64', length=425)
```

Would like to have

```
File_date Symbol hv5   hv10   dj20 hv20 hv50  hv100      Date  curiv    Days  Percentile  Close  Changed

20180413   ZYNE  23.04  34.22  30.61  73   67   65.0  180413.0  79.87   424.0        48.0  10.17        0
```

I tried

```
df_for_sql = pd.merge(df_allhv_to_date , df_clean ,  how='left', left_on=['File_date','Symbol'], right_on = ['File_date','Symbol'])
```

But it didn't work. What am I missing please?

Comment: Try `df_for_sql = pd.merge(df_allhv_to_date.rename_axis('File_date', axis=0).reset_index() , df_clean ,  how='left', left_on=['File_date','Symbol'], right_on = ['File_date','Symbol'])`

Comment: Looks like there is no `File_date` column in `df_allhv_to_date`, because it is being an index column instead.  Your join is on value columns, not index columns.

Comment: @ScottBoston Holy Zarquon's Singing Fish, SPOT on working like a champ. WOW! I love the way you have neatly corrected the file date issue. thank you so much I wouldn't have got anywhere close to this. I can't mark this as the answer as I don't have enough points. Thank you spark_spread as well

Comment: @sio2bagger I wrote an answer and condensed the code a little bit.

Comment: thanks again @ScottBoston I'm working through the whole line right now, I wouldn't have spotted that issue. My pandas needs work. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your date data in the 'df_allfv_to_date' is in the index.  So, I think we came first name the index, then move the data out of the index and join on these columns as follows:

```
df_for_sql =  pd.merge(df_allhv_to_date.rename_axis('File_date', axis=0).reset_index(), 
                       df_clean,  
                       how='left', 
                       on = ['File_date','Symbol'])
```